# Can I add the NET.Framework option on VS Studio 2022

Tags: c#

I have VS Studio 2022 & 2019 installed on my iMac, I tried to instal the 8.8 earlier version to enable the NET.Framework option, but the installer only updates the already preinstalled 2022 version. What should I do & how exactly should I do it?

Comment: .Net Framework is Windows only.

Comment: .NET Framework is specific to Windows. If you're using a mac you'll only be able to use .NET Core and .NET 5/6 (without a Windows VM).

Comment: .NET Core and .NET 5/6 applications still work on Windows as well, so if it's multiplatform support you're after then you'll be fine targeting .NET 6. All the core functionality that is in .NET Framework is still there, and for things that are missing there are libraries you can use to get the functionality back.